# How to wait for chrome.tabs.query?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I wait for the chrome.tabs.query result before proceeding with the code?

I have this code, which I  already tried many things, but I can't think of a way to make the code on chrome.tabs.query to execute completely before proceeding. The comment "LOG (background.js) clickGoButton done" is always first on the console ...

All this code is in background.js and it's running after I press a button in the extension popup.

```
function clickGoButton(){
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, async (tabs) => {
    const promiseArray = tabs.map(tab => {
        return execScript(tab);
    });

    const result = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
    console.log(result);
    console.log("Done");
})

chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log("LOG (background.js) clickGoButton done");
}

const execScript = (tab) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    /* Getting the selected text on the tab and saving into the result variable */
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: `document.getSelection().toString()` }, (result) => {

        /* Removing break lines from the selected text, saving the cleaned text on the group variable */
        var group = result[0].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");

        /* Selecting the chrome last focused tab */
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, function (tabs) {

            var param = "userNTID"
            var address = tabs[0].url;
            var domain = (new URL(address));

            var url_parameter = address.substr(address.indexOf(param))  
            var username = url_parameter.substring(url_parameter.lastIndexOf("=") + 1);
            chrome.storage.local.set({username: username}, function() {});
        });

        /* Multidimensional array containing the VDI Groups */
        var groups = []; // removed to keep short

        for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
            chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(groups[i][0]);

            if(groups[i][0] === group){

                chrome.storage.local.set({ad_group: groups[i][0]}, function() {});
                chrome.storage.local.set({farm: groups[i][1]}, function() {});
                chrome.storage.local.set({pool: groups[i][2]}, function() {});
                chrome.storage.local.set({assignment: groups[i][6]}, function() {});
                chrome.storage.local.set({source: groups[i][5]}, function() {});
                chrome.storage.local.set({machine: ''}, function() {});
            }
        }
        resolve("Done");
    });
});
}
```

Comment: You need to move the "subsequent" code into the callback of query(). Alternatively, promisify query(), then simply use async/await like you already do in other places.

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite get what you meant.